# Is the answer of a problem about the equation of a straight line given by my book wrong?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

This is the problem and the answer given by my book:

[image]

**My solution:**

$3x+\sqrt{3}y+2=0...(i)$

$x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha=p...(ii)$

Since (i) & (ii) are equations of the same straight line,

$$\frac{3}{\cos\alpha}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{2}{-p}$$

$$\implies -3p=2\cos\alpha...(i)$$

$$\implies -\sqrt{3}p=2\sin\alpha...(ii)$$

$(i)^2+(ii)^2:-$

$$9p^2+3p^2=4\cos^2\alpha+4\sin^2\alpha$$

$$\implies 12p^2=4$$

$$\implies p^2=\frac{1}{3}$$

$$\implies \sqrt{p^2}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$$

$$\implies |p|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

$$\implies p=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Why did the book pick only the negative value of $p$?

[Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4242175/768162)

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $\alpha$ given in the preceding text?

Comment: @BrianMoehring No.

Comment: The intended solution path starting from $ax+by+c=0$ is probably just the division by $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, as that would reduce the pair of the first two coefficients to a point on the unit circle.

Comment: Which book? You should always include that, as it can be helpful in case you missed some context. Also, have you searched for errata for the book or tried to check whether newer versions of the book says the same? And try to post text as text, not as an image (or as both, so it's not the end of the world if you mistyped something).

Comment: The form $x\cos\alpha+y\sin\alpha=p$ is unique if you take $\alpha\in[0,\pi)$, which is possibly what the book wants.

Comment: Looking at the CUET symbol I assume it's a book based on Bangladeshi syllabus. However, $p$ is always positive because it represents a perpendicular distance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that $p$ needn't be negative: $$3x+\sqrt{3}y+2=0,$$ $$x\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)+y\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},$$ and $$x\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)+y\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$ are all [represented by the same line](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2clzjuvyu0).